# bootstrap navbar collapsing social icons on top of one another

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I want a navbar that has a collapsible element on the right that holds my social media links and icons. Trouble is, the bootstrap navbar does not seem to be working: https://jsfiddle.net/44mbr237/1/

When the browser window is collapsed, the social media icons and links pile up on top of the collapsed icon (on the right).

html:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-comment"></i></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-facebook"></i></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-twitter"></i> </span>
      </button>
      <div class="navbar-brand">
          <img alt="PG Logo" src="http://newsinteractive.post-gazette.com/hbcu/img/PGLogoTwitter_2_10_12_bigger.gif">
      </div>
    </div>
    <h1 class="navbar-text">HEADER HERE</h1>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">


      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><i class="fa fa-2x fa-comment"></i></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://newsinteractive.post-gazette.com/hbcu/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/pgHBCU"><strong>#pgHBCU</strong></a> </li>
        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?original_referer=http%3A%2F%2Fnewsinteractive.post-gazette.com%2Fhbcu%2F&text=%23pgHBCU Pittsburgh high school students' perspectives on historically black colleges(via @PittsburghPG):&:tw_p=tweetbutton&url=http://newsinteractive.post-gazette.com/hbcu/" target="_blank"> <i class="fa fa-2x fa-twitter"></i> </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

css

```
    .navbar {
    height: 73px;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    border: none 0 !important;
    background-color: black !important;
    color: white !important;
}
.navbar-brand {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.navbar-brand img {
    border-right: 2px solid white;
}
.navbar-text {
    color: white !important;
    font-family: "Open Sans Condensed", sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/44mbr237/8/

You are adding the social icons to the button instead of adding it to the collapsable div and you also need to specify a height to your navbar so it can accomodate your navbar-brand image logo like this:

```
.navbar {
    height: 55px;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    border: none 0 !important;
    background-color: black !important;
    color: white !important;
}
```

Also add your navbar-brand as a anchor rather than a div

Comment: both the fiddle and my page.

Comment: hmmmm.... that's weird. Can you try hovering the toggle button till the mouse cursor changes to a hand and then click it on the jsfiddle please. (Reason I'm asking you to do that is because the small "Results" box by jsfiddle is covering the button

Comment: Check if you have include your bootstrap.js after jQuery.js in your `<head></head>` tag

Comment: It's working now--must be the gremlins. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle- Navbar](https://jsfiddle.net/vanntile/xkhepeow/1/)

This is what you need.

First of all you need to include jQuery.
Then, the h1 title shouldn't be placed there, but in the brand.
This is the code:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="img-responsive" alt="PG Logo" src="http://newsinteractive.post-gazette.com/hbcu/img/PGLogoTwitter_2_10_12_bigger.gif"/></a>
        <h4 class="navbar-text">HEADER HERE</h4>
    </div>


    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-2x fa-comment"></span></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://newsinteractive.post-gazette.com/hbcu/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/pgHBCU"><strong>#pgHBCU</strong></a></li>
              </li>
            <li><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?original_referer=http%3A%2F%2Fnewsinteractive.post-gazette.com%2Fhbcu%2F&text=%23pgHBCU Pittsburgh high school students' perspectives on historically black colleges(via @PittsburghPG):&:tw_p=tweetbutton&url=http://newsinteractive.post-gazette.com/hbcu/" target="_blank"> <i class="fa fa-2x fa-twitter"></i> </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


.navbar-brand {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.navbar-brand img {
    border-right: 2px solid white;
    height:51px;
}
.navbar-text {
    color: white !important;
    font-family:"Open Sans Condensed", sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
    margin-left:15px;
}
```

Edit:

Try this:[Second JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vanntile/xkhepeow/)

Comment: It's almost there, but now the navbar is very thick and the li items in the navbar-right are stacking up roughly one over the other.